# Christoffel Symbol Regularity

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a general pseudo-Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is in $H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, can we say that $\Gamma^i_{ij} \in H^{k - 1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Since Christoffel symbols involve one derivative of the metric, this is perhaps the expected result. However, the formula involves a metric inverse and quickly it gets messy to verify. I was wondering if there was a slick proof of this (if it is true).

Comment: Since $g$ is nondegenerate almost everywhere, you can define the Christoffel symbols almost everywhere. However, for them to be in $H^{k-1}$, more assumptions are needed. If $k > \frac{n}{2}$, then $g$ is continuous and nondegenerate, which implies that $g^{-1}$ is continuous and nondegenerate. In that case, you can show that the Christoffel symbols are in $H^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

In general I’d only expect this locally. To get the full statement, you’d need bounds on the inverse metric, which roughly translate to ‘lower bounds’ on the metric. Then, you’d need some result about multiplying Sobolev functions (since $\Gamma$ is a sum of terms like $g^{\cdot\cdot}\frac{\partial g_{\cdot\cdot}}{\partial x^{\cdot}}$), such as $H^{s}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ being an algebra if $s>\frac{n}{2}$.

To see an obvious counterexample, consider the 1D case, with $g=f(t)\,dt^2$ being a metric on $\Bbb{R}$. Then, the Christoffel symbol is (there is only 1) $\Gamma(t)=\frac{f’(t)}{f(t)}= (\log f)’(t)$. So, consider $f(t)=e^{-t^2}$, which is a Schwartz function, but $\Gamma(t)=-2t$, which is smooth but only locally integrable.